# How to mount S3 bucket to ecs fargate container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an `aws` ecs `fargate` cluster. it is a ecs-fargate cluster not an ecs-ec2 cluster. And I am running some containers where I need to mount a volume. Is it possible to mount an `s3` bucket to this fargate container?

If so, how can I do that?

If not, what are the other options I can follow? I want to preserve these data for later use (for disaster recovery and also for later access)

Comment: S3 isn't a filesystem that you mount.  You interact with it via a HTTP api, usually wrapped in a SDK. So at run time you'd call a S3 api from your application code to download any objects you need, perform your operations, then re-upload the data to S3 when you're done. If you need more of a filesystem, look into EFS

Comment: Although things for mounting S3 exists, none of them are good. S3 is not an actual filesystem, its a flat object database so trying to use it as a local filesystem is subpar at best. You can interact with s3 via the API from your containers, or you can mount efs volumes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html

Comment: You cannot move around S3 bucket like that.

Comment: The most obvious solution would be using s3fs which allows you to mount. However,  I did some small test. S3fs first caches a file on a local folder and then starts to copy / read from s3. So, if you want to copy a 1 GB file, it actually will use 2GB during the operation. That sounds to me like a bad concept, only for small files.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, mounting S3 is a bad idea, and it won't work in your Fargate containers anyway. Currently the only option for mounting external volumes in Fargate is to use [Amazon EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-ecs-aws-fargate-support-amazon-efs-filesystems-generally-available/).

Comment: If we are using EFS, is there a way I can see the data (visualize), and backup for disaster recovery?

Comment: It's just files on a file system, you can use them however you want. As for backup, there is an automated backup solution: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/awsbackup.html

Comment: Thank you, how is the visualization? Can I ftp into that and see?

Comment: By visualization do you mean browse the files? You would have to mount the file system (it uses NFS) on a server in order to access them like that.

Comment: Yes, to browse the files, can we not use another tool do this?

Comment: You can only browse the files by NFS mounting the EFS volume, there is no other way at this time.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there no direct way to mount s3 buckets to ecs tasks.
One option you can follow is by using AWS DataSync to sync s3 bucket into efs , and mount efs to your ecs task. [here](https://blog.searce.com/moving-data-between-s3-and-efs-using-datasync-e34fbf620430) is a great article on how you can implement such task

DataSync is a great solution if you want to sync the data periodically every x hours/days.

If you need the data to be synced inside the container the exact moment you make a change in your s3 bucket, you can trigger a lambda function that will sync the data for every new upload to s3, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html